# RKRelationshipConnectionOperation managedObject invalid in start method

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I'm having an issue using RestKit and trying to connect two entities using foreign keys.

Let's say I have two entities A and B and a relationship A <->> B
I create the connection in the following way

```
RKEntityMapping *aEntity = ...;
[aEntity addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary: ...]

RKEntityMapping *bEntity = ...;
[bEntity addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary: ...]

RKConnectionDescription *aConnection = [[RKConnectionDescription alloc] 
                                        initWithRelationship:[[b.entity
                                        relationshipsByName][@"a"]
                                                  attributes:@{@"aID" : @"id"}];
[bEntity addConnection:aConnection];
```

When data is received from the server I get an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` exception.
The exception fires in the following method:
`static NSDictionary *RKConnectionAttributeValuesWithObject(RKConnectionDescription *connection, NSManagedObject *managedObject)`
at the line `id sourceValue = [managedObject valueForKey:sourceAttribute];`

This method is called in the `RKRelationshipConnectionOperation` runloop.
What I noticed is that the `managedObject` is valid when the operation is created (in the init), but becomes invalid in the `start` method (the debugger gives the address, but no information on the object is printed)

I couldn't find any related issue, so I'm sure I'm missing something

EDIT: Regarding the comments, maybe this is the reason why this does not work.
I fetch before all the A entities.
In a separate fetch, I fetch some B entities. The JSON is something like

```
{
   "id" : 1,
   "someattr" : "somevalue",
   "aID" : 5
}
```

Comment: What is the incoming JSON? Connecting to a new object? Fetch request blocks?

Comment: @Wain I've updated the question

Comment: When you say fetch you mean query to the server, or fetch request? Are all objects from the server, or did you explicitly create one in code?

Comment: Sorry.. I mean query to the server. All the objects are obtained from the server except one of the A entity which is created manually and inserted in the managed object context (at the same time all the other objects are obtained from the server). BTW: I'm using 0.24. Do you think I should update to 0.25? I cannot see any change log on the github page

Comment: Yes, update. Are you saving that `A` instance, and getting a perm id for it?

Comment: I updated to 0.25 and the issue seems to be solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Restkit 0.25 solved the issue.